# how to hide rows that dont have data in the row

Tags: excel, vba

```html
Public Sub caInvCompressRows(p_strInv As String)

Dim intRow As Integer
Dim intRowMch As Integer
Dim intCol As Integer
Dim bUsed As Boolean
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strSheet As String
Dim intSaveRow As Integer
strSheet = "cordINV-" & p_strInv
Call utlUnProtectSheet(strSheet, "alcatraz")
Sheets(strSheet).Select
Cells.Select
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Range("A1").Select
intRowMch = caINV_ROW_FIRST
While Cells(intRowMch, 1).Value <> "" Or Cells(intRowMch, 11).Value <> ""
    For intRow = intRowMch + 1 To intRowMch + 6
        If Cells(intRow, 1).Value = "" Then
            If Cells(intRow, 11).Value = "" Then
                Rows(intRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next intRow
    intRowMch = intRowMch + 9
Wend

End Sub
```

[image: excel sheet example]

I want to hide rows that don't have data in them with the use of a button. each row contains three different groups of data that change which rows would need to be hidden. all data is pulled into columns C, O and AC and the rest is populated from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub HideRows()
 If Range("d2").Value = "" Then
    If Range("r2").Value = "" Then
        If Range("af2").Value = "" Then
```

Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    End If
    End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This formula checks if there is anything in row 2, simply by concatenating the whole row, trimming the result, and check if it is nothing but an empty string:

```
=TRIM(TEXTJOIN("";FALSE;2:2))=""
```

Comment: I attempted to use this and I think trim is only to remove spaces unless I wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: I've added the `TRIM()` in order also to remove spaces (which look blank but aren't). But if you regard a space as a non-blank and you want rows with spaces not to become invisible, then don't use the ´TRIM()´ function.

Comment: each cell in my worksheet has a formula in it to pull the data in from another sheet that looks similar. I tired to us this code in a vba button and it wouldn't work. I cant put this into a cell because it wouldn't allow the cell to auto populate from the other workbook.